# WebSetup for the WCF service

Tags: wcf

How to create the set up project for the WCF service . I created the set up for the WCF and added primary out file . But i could not see the Web.config and svc files. what is the issue. Please clarify

Thanks In Advance
Sekar

Answer (score 6):

Aswell as the "Primary Output" you also need to add the "Content Files" from your project.

Edit: [Here](http://blogs.cardwells.org/gis/2008/10/08/creating-installer-for-a-web-service-in-visual-studio-2008/) is a blog entry which details all the steps.

Comment: The blog above seems to have moved here: 
http://blogs.cardwells.org/gis/2008/10/08/creating-installer-for-a-web-service-in-visual-studio-2008/

Answer (score 2):

And make sure that .svc and .config files are marked as "Content" (files properties in VS solution).